# how do i read the first line only of a text file which contains numbers and do maths with it?

Tags: c#

I have a text file which contains a list of numbers. the first line is 5.5, the second line is 8 third line is 13 and so on. Each text file generates a list of number different each time but I'm only concentrating on the first line which in this case is 5.5, here is my code

```
                StreamReader FileFav = new StreamReader(BettingFileFav);
                StreamReader FileOdds = new StreamReader(BettingFileOdds);
                StreamReader FileResult = new StreamReader(BettingFileResult);
                FavLine = FileFav.ReadLine();
                OddsLine = FileOdds.ReadLine();
                ResultLine = FileResult.ReadLine();
                int BetAmount = 10;

                if (FavLine.Contains("Yes"))
                {
                    int a = Convert.ToInt16(OddsLine);
                    double c = ((double)a * BetAmount);
                    string myString = c.ToString("#.##");
                    MessageBox.Show("Won £" + myString);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Lost -£" + BetAmount); 
                }
```

the line of text it has read reads 5.5 so I am trying to get the answer 55.50.
I get an error code

> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

I'm using the MessageBox.Show to see if it works then migrating the result to a file which I will be using later.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Why are you trying to convert it to an `int` and then cast it to a  `double`? Why not convert to `double` straight away?

Comment: Also, what is the value of `OddsLine` when you (obviously) ran it under the debugger?

Comment: You're trying to parse 5.5 (a floating point value) to an Int16: `int a = Convert.ToInt16(OddsLine);`. Why would you possibly think that would work? And why didn't you spot it when the error happened on that exact line of code?

Comment: Oddsline is 5.5, I'm trying to multiply the first line in the FileOdds file by BetAmount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, you are trying to convert a floating point number to an integer, which is not accepted by `Convert.ToInt16`. The function requires the string to represent an actual signed integer value that fits within 16 bits, as described in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/basyfs27(v=vs.110).aspx).

However based on your following calculation, what you really want to do is convert the string to a `double` straight away, so you should use [`Convert.ToDouble`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

So the lines

```
int a = Convert.ToInt16(OddsLine);
double c = ((double)a * BetAmount);
```

should become

```
double a = Convert.ToDouble(OddsLine);
double c = (a * BetAmount);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm still learning and seem to make a few silly mistakes, it makes sense now and has worked